# Converting string to tuple in Erlang

Tags: string, erlang, tuples, ejabberd

How to convert string to tuple in Erlang?

```erlang
A = "{"hi","how"}"
```

And I want it to converted into

```
B = {"hi","how"}.
```

When I call function `list_to_tuple(A)` it gives output:

```erlang
{123,60,60,34,106,105,100,34,62,62,44,34,104,105,34,125}
```

rather than `{"hi","how"}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [erl_scan](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_scan.html) module to tokenize the string and [erl_parse](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html) to convert the tokens to a erlang term.

```erlang
% Note the '.' at the end of the expression inside string.
% The string has to be a valid expression terminated by a '.'.
1> Str = "{\"x\",\"y\"}.".  
"{\"x\",\"y\"}."
2> {ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(Str).
{ok,[{'{',1},
     {string,1,"x"},
     {',',1},
     {string,1,"y"},
     {'}',1},
     {dot,1}],
    1}
3> {ok, Tup} = erl_parse:parse_term(Ts).
{ok,{"x","y"}}
4> Tup.
{"x","y"}
```