# Convert a string representation of a tuple to a real tuple

Tags: parsing, erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

How to convert this string  `"[{type,a},{to,room01023123},{body,hey what's up mister},{by,someone}]"` into a tuple like this `[{"type","a"},{"to","room01023123"},{"body","hey what's up mister"},{"by","someone"}]`

Comment: That is not a valid Erlang tuple, specifically the `{body,hey what's up mister}` part. Is this just a made up example?

Comment: And do you want to do it in Erlang or in Elixir?

Comment: If you fix the quoting in the string to make it valid, and add a period to the end of the string, like this: `"[{\"type\",\"a\"},{\"to\",\"room01023123\"},{\"body\",\"hey what's up mister\"},{\"by\",\"someone\"}]."` then you can use `erl_scan:string/1` and `erl_parse:parse_term/1` as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28578482/409228).

Comment: @PatrickOscity sorry I removed the elixir tag, it's for erlang

Answer (score 5):

If you need to read from file, just use `file:consult`

```
-spec consult(Filename) -> {ok, Terms} | {error, Reason}
```

Otherwise you can use `erl_parse` module combined with `erl_scan` for this. In the simplest case like this

```
{ok, Tokens, _Line} = erl_scan:string("{hello, world}."),
erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens).
```

And don't forget that terms should end with full stop.

Comment: `file:consult/1` won't work in this case, because the term isn't valid. And the `erl_scan` and `erl_parse` part of the answer is a duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28579217/409228).

Comment: @SteveVinoski if term is not valid the first step is to make term valid of course :)

Comment: Sure, in which case this question is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28578482/409228).

Comment: @SteveVinoski, pretty much. Still answer is not exact duplicate as reading config from files is common task